# compare two name string php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am having a problem with comparing name strings.
I have 3 variables

```
$fullname  = 'MASNAD HOSSAIN NEHITH';
$firstName = 'Masnad';
$LastName  = 'Nehith';

$fullname2  = 'MÄSNAD HOSSAIN NEHITH';
$firstName2 = 'Mäsnad';
$LastName2  = 'Nehith';
```

I thought of using `strpos` to see if the first name exists in the full name, but `strpos` is case sensitive.

I tried regular expressions using pregmatch but I am not sure how it works.

```
$pregmatch = preg_match("/$fullname/", $firstName);
if($pregmatch){
   echo " it matches";
 }
$pregmatch2 = preg_match("/$fullname2/", $firstName2);
if($pregmatch2){
   echo " it matches";
 }
```

Comment: You can use `stripos()` for case insensitive http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: heh, there's a `stripos` for case insensitive check

Comment: @jitendrapurohit: since the strings may contain accented character, you should use `mb_stripos` instead, otherwise `stripos` in unable to see that `ä` is the lowercase of `Ä`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_match` function with `ui` modifiers(to match *UTF-8* characters and match both upper and lower case letters):

```
$fullname2 = 'MÄSNAD HOSSAIN NEHITH';
$firstName2 = 'Mäsnad';

if (preg_match("/$firstName2/ui", $fullname2)){
    echo "it matches";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`mb_stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php) instead of simple [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) for `UTF-8` characters like as

```
if(mb_stripos('MÄSNAD HOSSAIN NEHITH', 'Mäsnad') !== false)
{
    echo "UTF - 8 string".PHP_EOL;
}

if(mb_stripos('MASNAD HOSSAIN NEHITH', 'Masnad') !== false)
{
    echo "Normal String";
}
```

**Output**

```
UTF - 8 string
Normal String
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/u4eJt)

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the case insensitive version of `strpos()`: `stripos()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Also, if your code has utf8 chars (which is the case here), use `mb_stripos()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php

An other way is to convert all your strings to upper or lower case before comparison

Many string functions in php have an insensitive case equivalent with just  an additionnal "i" in their name (`strstr` => `stristr`, `str_replace` => `str_ireplace` ...)

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason it cant match the lastname string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use "" or '' sign when defining a variable with string value.

```
$fullname = 'MASNAD HOSSAIN NEHITH';
$firstName = 'Masnad';
$LastName = 'Nehith';

$fullname2 = 'MÄSNAD HOSSAIN NEHITH';
$firstName2 = 'Mäsnad';
$LastName2 = 'Nehith';
```

then you can use stripos() instead of strpos().